# Number of complex solutions

Tags: problem-solving

Given the following equation:

$$ x^{259}=1  $$

$$ x^{413}=1  $$

How many complex solutions for x have?

Thanks

Comment: I count *two* equations... Is that a system or two independent equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are seven solutions of the form $e^{i2k\pi/7}$ for $k=0,...,6$, because the common factor of 259 and 413 is 7. Six of them are "complex" and the other one ($k=0$) is just $1$.

Comment: "Common factor" being gcd(413,259)

Comment: $1$ is a perfectly good complex number too

Comment: Yeah, if real numbers were not complex, the complex plane wouldn't be connected.

Comment: That's why I put "complex" in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that $x$ must satisfy *both* equations, note that $\gcd(259,413)=7$.

Prove now:

1. Every $7$th root of $1$ satisfies both equations.
2. Every solution $x$ of both equations must be a $7$th root of $1$. *Hint*: use Bezout's identity.